# Append text with dynamic value in a text file by echo command in bash

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, shell

I want to append some text in a file through a shell script.

I have the following script

`bash -c 'echo -e "\nserver.id=$1" >> file.properties'`

saved in the file `script.sh`

This is how I run the script `sh script.sh ABC`.

But only `server.id=` is appended and not `server.id=ABC`.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
bash -c 'echo -e "\nserver.id='$1'" >> file.properties'
```

should be working. Note that $1 is actually not in quotes.